# function with double mode of functionality

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, function, cql

I have a function which should have two modes of behaviour according to the place where it's called from.

The core functionality is to do an insert into a table in my database, but it has to be done in two different ways.

1. Normal mode: whenever it's called only one time (outside of a loop)

For example:
   
`//...
myfunc(param1, record); // it should insert a single record into the database
//...`

1. Batch mode: whenever it's called from inside of a loop

For example:

```
    while(...){ 

      myfunc(param1, record); 

    }
```

Inside the "while" loop, each time it's called, it only should store the record in a list and when it reaches the end of the loop, it should fetch all records from the list and prepare a "batch" query that inserts all in one go.

I am wondering how to make it to detect from where it's called in order to switch to the corresponding mode and also how to detect that it has reached the end of a loop and from now on, it should start getting records from the list, prepare the query and execute it.

Any tips or suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Thanks heaps!

Comment: I don't think that can be done. You probably need to use different functions.

Comment: Even if you could do this it would be very bad design - a function should be self-contained and should be oblivious to the context from which it was called.

Comment: You have to supply a flag as input to your function to flag its behavior accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that I am replacing c-isam calls and I have to have exactly the same parameters and return value type as the original calls in order to keep compatibility. Here is the c-isam function: int iswrite(int isfd, char *record)

Comment: This is clearly not possible. Double functionality = double functions.

Comment: The original c-isam calls can't do anything like you claim either. If they do different operations, it either depends on their arguments or global variables.

Comment: @PaulR, you understate. It is a *horrible* design, just considering it seriously should make you consider a change of carreer...

Answer (score 0):

It is not, in general, possible to tell whether you are being called in a loop, even with full source code access.

You might be able to do something with caching and delaying the actual database insert for a limited time in all cases. Go on caching until you go for x microseconds without a new call, and then insert the cached data.

However, that could give strange effects if you are not in control of all accesses to the database. In particular, you should do your cached inserts any time there is query that might be affected by them, even in a loop.

Comment: Thanks Patricia! Could please provide an example of implementation for delaying a call without blocking the process? There is no object used in my code!

Comment: Do a search for "c++ timer" (without the quotes). There are two basic options, use a library that implements a timer or explicitly reserve a thread that sleeps until it is time to do something.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is useful to cache queries like this in order to minimize the number of database queries. You can have one function that builds a cache and a second function that sends the request and flushes the cache. If you are going to do that, I recommend using the same function for both single-entry and multiple-entries. The pseudocode will look something like this:

**Single-entry usage:**

```
myfunc(param1, record); # caches requests
sendRequests();         # sends all cached requests, flushes cache
```

**Multiple-entry usage:**

```
while(...){ 
  myfunc(param1, record); 
}
sendRequests();
```

sendRequest() will send as many queries as it finds: 1 or many. For efficiency, it can format the requests differently based on their size.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I also had the same thought, but the problem is that I must not call any second function from the client class!